# Magento 1.9 Logo not being displayed on Shipping PDF

Tags: php, magento, pdf

When trying to print a delivery for an order in Magento the logo is not displaying. I have narrowed it down to the following line of code in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` line 133 in the `insertLogo()` method.

```
$image = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/filesystem/media', $store) . '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
```

I can't see that this option is being set anywhere and doesn't appear in the `core_config_data` table. Any ideas on getting this to work? Have I missed a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the logo for Invoice and Shipment using below steps:

1. From Top Navigation in Admin click on `system` >> `Configuration`
2. From Left click on `Sales` in `Invoice and Packing Slip Design` Group, You can upload the logo for PDF print out